# Android HttpPost get "Invalid request URI" from Youtube

Tags: android, youtube, http-post

I'm trying to access this URL to Youtube (phones are no proxy setting, direct to internet)

> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/music?q=gagamv&max-results=50&alt=json&v=2

The URL above I put in any PC browsers ware working well(Will return pure JSON String), even I didn't log-into Youtube.

But this URL I tried to access via Android's HttpPost, only I can get is **Invalid Request URI**

Here's my code :

```
    public static final String HEADER_TYPE="Content-Type";
    private static final String HEADER_TYPE_SET="application/text; charset=utf-8";
    public static final String HEADER_TYPE_2="Accept";
    private static final String HEADER_TYPE_SET_2="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    /** Socket操作逾時(3600秒) */
    public static final int TIMEOUT_SOCKET=7000;
    /** 連線逾時(3600秒) */
    public static final int TIMEOUT_CONECTION=7000;

    List<NameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    HttpParams httpP=null;
    DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient=null;
    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity=null;
    HttpResponse httpResp=null;
    String ret="";

    BasicHeader[] header=new BasicHeader[2];
    header[0]=new BasicHeader(HEADER_TYPE, HEADER_TYPE_SET);
    header[1]=new BasicHeader(HEADER_TYPE_2, HEADER_TYPE_SET_2);
    httpP=new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpP, TIMEOUT_CONECTION);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpP, TIMEOUT_SOCKET);
    String url=new String("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/music?q=gagamv&max-results=50&alt=json&v=2");
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Youtube search URL: "+url);
    HttpPost post=new HttpPost(url);
    mHttpClient=new DefaultHttpClient(httpP);

    entity=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);
    post.addHeader(entity.getContentType());
    post.setEntity(entity);
    httpResp=mHttpClient.execute(post);

    String status=httpResp.getStatusLine().toString();
    ret=new String(EntityUtils.toString(httpResp.getEntity(), "UTF-8"));
```

What can I do to overcome this problem ?

Comment: Why are you using POST?

Comment: you do realize you are not putting anything in params?

Comment: Oops, I spam hours on a stupid situation again...Thanks for your tip guy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the HTTP GET Request. The issue is you are using the HTTP Post and the url will return data when you use a get Request.

Try the following code ( I have taken the buffer size to 4096 but you can change that to be dynamic for your requirement):

```
        URL url = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/music?q=gagamv&max-results=50&alt=json&v=2");
           HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           try {
             InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
             byte buffer[] = new byte[4096];

             in.read(buffer);
             String str = new String(buffer);
             Log.d(TAG, " Data: " + str);

           } finally {
             urlConnection.disconnect();
           }
```

Comment: Other part of my code are using HttpPost to connect with my server, and I just copy that code to access Youtube, and forget to change to HttpGet...Thanks :-)